# How to tell eclipse preferred content type for a file

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, file-type

I'm working on a plugin that will handle files of a given type, say, `.xyz` when in Eclipse I try to open an `xyz` file. I'm trying to use

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.IContentType type = 
  org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getContentTypeManager().findContentTypeFor(
      fileURI.getPath());
```

I've got code to look up the needed factory once I have the `IContentType`.
I need to find out how to "register" my file type with Eclipse So when I select a file of my type to open, the Eclipse application knows to use my code to handle it. I've already gone to the Extensions tab of my `Manifest.MF` and added my Extension Element Details such as base-type, file-extensions, id (package where my code is) and name. But type still ends up as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to open the files with an editor. If I remember correctly (from a `.properties` editor example), your editor contribution should look like that:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor>
  ...
  <extensions>xyz,txt,jpg</extensions> <!-- .xyz .txt and .jpg files       --> 
  <default>true</default>              <!-- default editor for these types -->
  </editor>
</extension>
```